# SSRS 2008 Combining a bar graph with a line graph, using 2 series

Tags: ssrs-2008, bar-chart, linechart, series

I have a report that shows two series of data. The bar chart shows the current accounts receivable and the line chart shows the original AR balance.

[image]

For example, the current balances of charges for Sept 2015 is 35, and the original balance was 200. Oct 2015 current balance is 37, and the original was 325. Nov 2015 current balance is 45, and the original balance was 265. And so on.

I will create the query that has the two sets of data. What I want to know is, is SSRS 2008 powerful enough to show separate data series, one as a bar graph and the other as a line graph? I suspect the best I will be able to do is a stacked bar graph.

Edit: It was suggested that there was a similar question. My question is different because the other question was a solution of two charts side-by-side. I need a combined chart.

Comment: Yes it is.Just make sure the two series are in different columns and you can just add as many series as you want (in any representation - stacked, line etc.). Here are two examples on this very site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461908/two-chart-types-bar-and-line-in-same-ssrs-chart, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043229/draw-line-chart-on-top-of-bar-chart-in-ssrs

Comment: I've marked as duplicate even though the requirement is not quite the same, it does contain instructions.